# Apache with mixed HTTP only and HTTPS virtualhosts

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, virtualhost, https

I have Apache 2.4 on Debian 8 and few HTTP only name-based virtualhosts and (for now) just 1 HTTPS virtualhost signed by Let's Encrypt certificate. At this moment secured virtualhost works well, but if I visit other non-secured virtualhosts with `https://` I get content of the secured virtualhost. Is there some way to (in this case) make some redirection to HTTP or avoid loading content of the secured virtualhost site?

Comment: Don't. It's insecure. Redirect everything to https, use HSTS. Use CSP upgrade-insecure-ressources.

Answer (score 2):

Of course redirecting from https to http is possible with:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    SSLEngine on
    # All other SSL settings, just like in your working TLS VirtualHost.

    Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

You just have to understand that:

- This will first give a warning "Your connection is not private", because the hostname in HTTP `Host:` header doesn't match the your certificate, i.e. `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. Of course this is something you already get.
- Normal users don't write `http://` or `https://` in the address bar, just the `www.example.com`, which gets by default completed with `http://`. (Actually, some users don't even know about the address bar, but uses Google search instead, then picking the first result.)

I'd rather create a catch-all virtualhost with some default page explaining that there is no `TLS` site configured for this domain. Make sure this comes before the working virtualhost by using a filename that gets first on `apache2/sites-enabled`, like `001-tls`, and use `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are contradicting yourself. You can't visit non-secured virtualhosts using "https", https by default means port 443, which is the SSL virtualhost in all but rare cases, you will always land in your SSL virtualhost/s then.